# Same function but different input class

Tags: java, oop

I have a function that performs the following task:

```java
Double F(Class input){
    return input.getNumerator()/ input.getDenominator();
}
```

Now, I have two classes that will be using this same function, class A and class B and they look like this:

```java
class A {
    Long numerator;
    Long denominator;
    String firstName;
    //getters and setters
}

class B {
    Long numerator;
    Long denominator;
    String address;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Therefore class A and class B have some common variables/getter-setters but not all. Function F requires only the common variables of class A and class B. Now, I need to run function F for both classes, but I don't want to write the exact same function twice for each class and duplicate the code. I want to instead have the input for Function F in such a way that it can accept both Class A and Class B and use their common getter-setters. How should I proceed with this?

Comment: Create an abstract class or interface that contains the common methods of A and B, then have your method accept any object of that abstract class or interface.

Comment: Why don't you use POJO in both classes? You might not need to write the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the common attributes to a base class and have both `A` and `B` extend it:

```java
public abstract class AbstractFraction {
    protected Long numerator;
    protected Long denominator;

    // getters and setters
}

class A extends AbstractFraction {
    String firstName;
    // getter and setter for firstName
}

class B extends AbstractFraction {
    String address;
    // getter and setter for address
}

public class FractionUtil {
    Double F(AbstractFraction input) {
        return input.getNumerator()/ input.getDenominator();
    }
}
```